# How to use "layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect:)" method?

Tags: swift, face-detection, apple-vision

I am working with Apple's Vision framework for detecting faces. Then I come to this function.

```
let cgr: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)

let videoPreviewRect = previewLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: cgr)
```

where `previewLayer` is AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer type object. It is a conversion from metaDataOutput rect to view rect. But I don't understand it completely.

How does it work, what does it converts to what?

Answer (score 1):

So the idea here is that typically with something like Vision Framework or `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` you will get back normalised rectangle coordinates (e.g {0,0}-{1,1} range, think like a percentage of the total image).
However, if you want to draw them to the user you will likely going to need the coordinates in screen points.

The pair of methods of `layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect:)` and `metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect:)` will allow you to convert between these two coordinate systems and also takes into account `videoGravity` property of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` which otherwise makes it a pain to calculate things e.g. when `resizeAspectFill` gravity is used.